# symfony2 routing yml error - symblog tutorial

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

eclipse is marking a route that I took from the symfony2 blog tutorial.

Is the error correctly flagged or do I need to change my yml editor?

[image]

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: If my memory is correct on this, Symfony2 uses a custom YAML parser that does not require quotes around values with non-alphanumeric characters. The traditional YAML specification does. Try putting quotes around the value for `_controller`. It won't break Symfony and it should make Eclipse happy

Comment: like this?   
defaults: { "_controller": loggerBlogBundle:Default:index }

Comment: Almost, `{ _controller: "BloggerBlogBundle:Default:index" }`

Comment: You can add it as an answer below if you want and I will mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my memory is correct on this, Symfony2 uses a custom YAML parser that does not require quotes around values with non-alphanumeric characters. The traditional YAML specification does. Try putting quotes around the value for _controller. It won't break Symfony and it should make Eclipse happy

`{ _controller: "BloggerBlogBundle:Default:index" }`